# What will be the DFA for (0+1)*?

Tags: computation-theory

I have drawn this diagram below. But i want to be sure of the answer as + and the * operator are confusing.

```
     _  
    | \
--> q_|- 0,1,E
```

Here my DFA has only one state q. Both 0,1,empty are redirected to q itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(0+1) means you can select **a 0 or 1 but not both**. The + is analogous to OR.
The star means that you can do this selection **Zero or more times**.

Hence, (0+1)* will include any String of 0s and 1s including the empty string.

Comment: Why only strings of 0s and 1s? Consider 0101. Can i say that for the first letter, i will select the zero part and for the second, i will select the one's part and so on. So can this string be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

5 years late but heres what I got:

```
Start at A. A is also an end state.

From A: Input 0 goes to B. B is an end state.
        Input 1 goes to C. C is an end state.

From B: Input 0 goes to B.
        Input 1 goes to C.

From C: Input 0 goes to B.
        Input 1 goes to C.
```

I'm pretty sure this is right (studying for an exam atm)...

It may be hard to visualise from that but if you draw a diagram from my instructions it should be more clear.

Hope this helps anyone looking this up.

Answer (score 0):

Trick is whenever you see <kbd>*</kbd> means Kleene closure  so epsilon will enter
And .
When you see <kbd>+</kbd> send a and b sting differently not in series but parallel
And where you see concat . Send the string in series